# Flutter how can i alien an icon in a row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[My current screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/honnB.png),

[how I want it to lock like this made manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPt84.png)

How can I make the line of icons alined next to the left border?

My code is:

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 25.0),
            Text(
              "hello world"
            ),
            SizedBox(width: getWidth() * 185.0),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.check,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: can you share what is your expected output

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPt84.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way wrap your `Text` widget inside `Expanded()` widget it will work

```
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 25.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                    "hello world"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  size: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Tank you =, for the answer:)